# Springboot undertow

Tags: spring-boot, undertow

I have this maven app that starts spring boot. All are fine within the application. Want to try to switch tomcat to undertow, to test something. For some reason, despite my pom.xml, the undertow is not loaded.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
```

My pom snippet

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is not in what you show in your question. What you show is correct. I advise you to execute mvn `depdendency:tree` that will output the actual tree of dependency of your project. It could very probably help you to understand the issue cause.

Comment: You were right. Using mvn dep tree found out that Jersey is loading tomcat as well ... now it works

Comment: Fine ! A starter can indeed "hides" many things. I would have though of it : )

Answer (score 1):

Had to add exclusions in the jersey dependency as well. Jersey was including tomcat